# Slick Slider 2 sliders not matching slides and Slider inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

As you can see I have 2 slick sliders running in this page, One is seen by default and the second one is triggered in a bootstrap modal when user click one of the slides of the first one. This is to see the slide individually and in bigger size . My use case is simply this and I am super close to completing: *When user click any of the slide of the slider, a modal should pop up with slick slider with a 1 slideToShow option instead of 3 so the image is bigger, the slide that show on the Modal should be the same the one user clicked.*

**Issues**.
1. When page is refreshed and user click one of the slide, the modal slider opens to with a buggy view, once i start clicking the next and previous arrow , this goes away, why is this happening?
 see the bugg view:[image]
2. How do i show the same slide the user clicker on the modal also, right now modal slider opens like a new slider and the first slide is shown all the time not the one user clicked

```css
.stack-list-slider-slider-area {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .stack-list-slider-slide h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area button.slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: auto;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area button.slick-prev.slick-arrow:after {
    content: "<";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #00805f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area button.slick-next.slick-arrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 40px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area button.slick-next.slick-arrow:after {
    content: ">";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #00805f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .stack-list-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .stack-list-slider-slide {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .slider-img img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    padding: 0 15px !important;
}
.stack-list-slider-slider-area .stack-list-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
    padding: 0 40px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .stack-list-slider-modal-slide h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area button.slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: auto;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area button.slick-prev.slick-arrow:after {
    content: "<";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #00805f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area button.slick-next.slick-arrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 40px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area button.slick-next.slick-arrow:after {
    content: ">";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #00805f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .stack-list-modal-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .stack-list-slider-modal-slide {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .slider-img img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    padding: 0 15px !important;
}
.stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area .stack-list-modal-slider.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
    padding: 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Practice Html page</title>
    <!-- Slick Slider CSS CDN 3.3.1-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN 3.3.1-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head><!-- end head -->

<body>
    <div class="stack-list-slider-slider-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="stack-list-slider">
                <div class="stack-list-slider-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalId">
                    <div class="slider-img">
                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnbizh3joq3l71n/1.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                <div class="stack-list-slider-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalId">
                    <div class="slider-img">
                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9k753y33lfwnnnw/2.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                <div class="stack-list-slider-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalId">
                    <div class="slider-img">
                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dven42pc2o012j/3.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                <div class="stack-list-slider-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalId">
                    <div class="slider-img">
                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/feqzlynvgryieh5/4.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->



            </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider -->


        </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end slider area -->



    <!-- img gallary modal start -->

    <div id="modalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="stack-list-slider-modal-slider-area">
                            <div class="stack-list-modal-slider">
                                <div class="stack-list-slider-modal-slide" >
                                    <div class="slider-img">
                                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnbizh3joq3l71n/1.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                                <div class="stack-list-slider-modal-slide" >
                                    <div class="slider-img">
                                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9k753y33lfwnnnw/2.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                                <div class="stack-list-slider-modal-slide" >
                                    <div class="slider-img">
                                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dven42pc2o012j/3.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                                <div class="stack-list-slider-modal-slide" >
                                    <div class="slider-img">
                                        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/feqzlynvgryieh5/4.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                                </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider-slide -->
                
                
                
                            </div> <!-- /.stack-list-slider -->
                
                
                    </div><!-- end slider area -->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- img gallary modal ends -->

    <!-- Loading Jquery 3.4.0 CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Loading Jquery 3.4.0 CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Loading Slick Slider CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.stack-list-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: true,
                asNavFor: ".stack-list-modal-slider",


                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 991,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 767,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });

            $('.stack-list-modal-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: true,
                asNavFor: ".stack-list-slider",

            });

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is my answer is helpful to you ?

Comment: @MHFuad its still happening, now it doesn't show when clicking the first three slider , click next arrow and then click any slide to open modal and it shows again. i used this solution too from google , still no use $('.stack-list-modal-slider').not('.slick-initialized')

Comment: give me an upvote for my try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the "data-slick-index" when clicking the first slide and using that to set the modal slider using "slickGoTo" fixed the slide matching issue. As far as the bug goes Multiple fixes were needed
1) use "unslick" when not using modal slider and trigger modal slider only when modal is modal is open(thanks to MH Fuad), the bug seems to be happening due to multiple sliders in one page. Here is my jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           jQuery('.stack-list-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: true,
                infinite: true,
                asNavFor: ".stack-list-modal-slider",
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 991,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 767,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
        });
        var clickedSlick;

       jQuery('.stack-list-slider-slide').each(function () {

           jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var test =jQuery(this).closest('.slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
                console.log(test);
                clickedSlick = test;
            });

        })


       jQuery('.stack-list-slider .stack-list-modal-slider').removeClass('slick-active');

        //set active class to first thumbnail slides
       jQuery('.stack-list-slider .stack-list-modal-slider').eq(0).addClass('slick-active');



       jQuery('#modalId').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
           jQuery('.stack-list-modal-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows: true,
                infinite: true,
                asNavFor: ".stack-list-slider",
            });

           jQuery('.stack-list-modal-slider').slick('slickGoTo', clickedSlick);
        });
       jQuery("#modalId").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
           jQuery('.stack-list-modal-slider').slick('unslick')
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

add this section

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   //write your code here 
});
```

full code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.stack-list-slider').slick({
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: false,
arrows: true,
asNavFor: ".stack-list-modal-slider",
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 991,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 767,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
    }
  },
]
});
});

$('#modalId').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.stack-list-modal-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: false,
arrows: true,
asNavFor: ".stack-list-slider",
});
});
```

reference is here https://codepen.io/mhfuad/pen/yLNRagb

I think this is a solution for now